# Impact of data intervals in fast fourier transform

Tags: algorithm, math, fft

I have sampled sensor data for 1 minute with 5kHz sampling.
So, one sampled data file includes 5,000 x 60 = 300,000 data points.
Note that the sensor measures periodic data such as 60Hz AC current.

Now, I would like to apply FFT (using python numpy.rfft function) to the one data file.
As I know, the number of FFT results is half of the number of input data, i.e., 150,000 FFT results in the case of 300,000 data points.
However, the number of FFT results is too large to analyze them.

So, I would like to reduce the number of FFT results.
Regarding that, my question is that the following method valid given the one sampled data file?

1. Segment the one sampled data file into M segments
2. Apply FFT to each segment
3. Average the M FFT results to get one averaged FFT result
4. Use the average FFT result as FFT result of the given one sampled data file

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your purposes.

If source signal is sampled with 5 kHz, then frequency of max output element will corresponds to 2.5 kHz. So for 150K output length **frequency resolution** will about 0.017 Hz. If you apply transform to 3000 data points, you'll get freq.resolution 1.7 Hz.

Is this important for you? Do you need to register  all possible frequency components of AC current?

AC quality (magnitude, frequency, noise) might vary during one-minute interval. Do you need to register such instability?

Perhaps, high freq. resolution and short-range temporal stability is not necessary for AC control, in this case you approach is quite well.

**Edit:** Longer interval also diminishes finite-duration signal windowing effect that gives false peaks

P.S. Note that fast Fourier transform usually (not always, I don't see such directions in rfft description) works with `interval length = 2^N`, so here output might contain 256K